# Database validation in application

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I have a c# application add-on from which I need to validate the schema of a database.  I can't use any of the obvious frameworks due to limitations of the application I'm extending, but rather need to find an alternative method to confirm whether database procedures exist and or whether they need to be updated (if the procedure itself was changed from what is expected).  Aside from writing individual queries for each procedure are there any better solutions I might consider?

Comment: Validate the schema how? Do you have a build time list of tables / columns / procs? Run time? Is it dynamic?

Comment: There are hundred or so database proceedures I need to validate (i.e. make sure it hasn't changed) and a few dozen tables I need to test to make sure fields are as expected.  It's not sufficient to assume these won't be changed by the application I'm building off of or that a user won't make changes to the table schema.  As the workflows I'm building are failing due to these unanticipated changes I'm trying to find a way to test and automate repair.

Comment: Why and how are users changing schema objects?  It sounds like you need security on the database to only allow changes to certain users.  What you have now is a security nightmare.  Additionally, if the schema has changed then what do you do - rollback?

Comment: I use the underlying database objects but do not own all of the elements of it and cannot restrict access... I know.  It sucks and this whole project has basically been me hacking at things...

Comment: I would guess anything you would do would be a performance hog.  Generating scripts through SSMS for a 'normal' sized database can take 30+ mins.  Running from c# code will take even longer.  I would really push to lock-down your database - I don't expect anything you do from a front-end will be performant.

Answer (score 0):

There is database project in visual studio. You can import your database to this project and try to build. Please see official documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/import-into-a-database-project?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: can this be embedded into my existing application or do I need to deploy this as a separate solution?

Comment: @ShaunLangley It is just a project(like class library or console application). It is possible to add new project to existing solution

Comment: well that is probably the "correct" way to do this but unfortunately my VS2015 cannot import a 2017 database... the application I'm extending does not support a newer VS project.

Comment: Check property of your project. You can change target sql server to 2017

Comment: 2016 is the newest target available to me

Comment: Another way. Open Server explorer window in VS, find your database, right click than import

Answer (score 0):

```
<twocents>
```

1. Export all your objects to .SQL files and commit them to source control and write them out into a folder on disk.
2. Create a tracker table that maps the object you have exported to a hash of the DDL of the object.
3. Inspect the objects in the database when your app initialises or at some other appropriate time.
4. Compare the hash of the DDL of the database object in the database with what is on the disk. If there is a disparity drop and recreate the object by executing the DDL of the file on disk

The hash acts as fast way to check if what's in the database matches the structure of the object that you expect to be in the database. How you deploy it is questionable, but the assumption I am making is that you are in control of your database objects that you have exposed to the application.

```
</twocents>
```

Comment: Not saying that it's not a pain to export all your objects out to SQL files